# What does `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` specify?

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

Having read the docs and done a little looking around I'm still unclear.

The title largely sums up the question, but to ask a more specific question:

Given a shader with a single binding and it's binding being:

```c
layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffer {
    uint x[];
};
```

I know that setting `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount = 1` works:

```cpp
VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo = {};
{
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding binding = {};
    {
        binding.binding = 0;
        binding.descriptorCount = 1; 
        binding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT;
    }
    
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.bindingCount = 1;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.pBindings = &binding;
}
```

In changing `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` to 2 or some other value, what would I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` says the number of descriptors (in your case uniform buffers) the binding has. For example, lets say that we have an array of buffers,

```
layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffers {
    uint x[];
} buffers[5];
```

Then the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` should be equal to 5 and also should be said for `VkDescriptorPoolSize::descriptorCount`.

Since you only have one buffer, stating 1 is enough.

Comment: Little mess up by me at the end of the question there, question is about what `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount` specifies, so what affect changing it would have, apologies for accidently putting `VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo::bindingCount` at the end for a sec.

Comment: while:
`layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffers {
    uint x[];
} buffers[5];`

should it be:
`.binding = 0,
.descriptorCount = 5,//not 1,`
for VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding in VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo when vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout ?

Comment: while:
`layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffers {
    uint x[];
} buffers[5];`

should it be:
`.type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
.descriptorCount = 5,//not 1,`
for VkDescriptorPoolSize in VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo when vkCreateDescriptorPool?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409366/whats-the-difference-between-descriptorcount-in-vkdescriptorpoolsize-and-in-vk
please come here and help, thanks!