# what's the difference between .descriptorCount in VkDescriptorPoolSize and in VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo)? how set?

Tags: gpu, shader, vulkan

what's the difference between .descriptorCount in VkDescriptorPoolSize and in VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo)?
how to set them when there are many shaders, how to set them correctly?

eg.

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform Buffers {
    uint x[];
} buffers[5];
```

then:

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 5,//not 1,
VkDescriptorPoolSize.descriptorCount = 5,//not 1,
```

what if this same uniform Buffers are in many shaders? should add 5 to descriptorCount when it exist in 1 more shader?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you think a descriptor set actually is, what a descriptor pool actually is, and how the two are related to one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount`. The spec says:

> descriptorCount is the number of descriptors contained in the binding,
> accessed in a shader as an array, except if descriptorType is
> VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK in which case descriptorCount
> is the size in bytes of the inline uniform block. If descriptorCount
> is zero this binding entry is reserved and the resource must not be
> accessed from any stage via this binding within any pipeline using the
> set layout.

So most likely be `1`, unless you have an array of textures or array of uniform buffers (which is not very common).

---

`VkDescriptorPoolSize::descriptorCount` has nothing to do with the previous one. A descriptor pool is used for allocating descriptors. So `descriptorCount` here is how many descriptors this pool can provide. The spec says:

> descriptorCount is the number of descriptors of that type to allocate.
> If type is VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK then
> descriptorCount is the number of bytes to allocate for descriptors of
> this type.

You can use the same pool for allocating multiple descriptor sets of multiple different layouts. So this most likely needs to be a fairly large number.

---

Anyways, I think you need to keep studying the general basic concepts around descriptors!