# What does descriptorCount mean in VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding?

Tags: vulkan

I use all this to create a uniform buffer. I would like to make sure I understand it correctly. DescriptorCount refers to the number of elements in the array that the shader accepts. So if the shader took vec4 vecs[5], the descriptorCount value would be 5, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount\` specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772848/what-does-vkdescriptorsetlayoutbindingdescriptorcount-specify)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `descriptorCount` refers to the number of elements that the binding has (1 for single elements, > 1 for arrays).

So to create this uniform configuration

```c
layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffer { uint x[]; } single;
layout(binding = 1) buffer Buffer { uint x[]; } array[5];
```

you would have to specify two bindings with different descriptor counts.

```cpp
std::array<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding, 2> bindings{{
    .binding = 0,
    .descriptorCount = 1, 
    ...
},{
    .binding = 1,
    .descriptorCount = 5, 
    ...
}};

VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    .bindingCount = bindings.size();
    .pBindings = bindings.data();
}
```